# Why can't I set a top margin?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to make a BBC News clone and for some reason the css won't let me set a margin-top to my Sign In text. I don't understand what's wrong with the specificity or the container. Everything else works, the font-size, font color. `

```
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <a href="https://www.bbc.com/news" target="_blank">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="bbc" id="logo">
        </a>
        <div id="signin" class="topbar-section">
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle" id="account-image"></i>
            <span id="signin-text">Sign In</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#topbar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
}

#logo {
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 85px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
   
}

.topbar-section {
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
    height: 100%;
    
}

#account-image {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 12px 15px;
}

 #signin-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: You have an extra space before `#signin-text` selector.

Comment: @ArtyGator I'm afraid that's not the issue, it still doesn't work with or without the extra space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#topbar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
}

#logo {
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 85px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
   
}

.topbar-section {
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#account-image {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 12px 15px;
}

#signin-text {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <a href="https://www.bbc.com/news" target="_blank">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="bbc" id="logo">
        </a>
        <div id="signin" class="topbar-section">
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle" id="account-image"></i>
            <span id="signin-text">Sign In</span>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes sir! Thank you so much! I've been stuck on it for hours. I really appreciate it

Comment: If my answer worked, can you check my answer is correct? Thank you. :)

Comment: I was so frustrated about it, it never even crossed my mind to use Flexbox

Comment: Yes I will check it as correct, of course

Comment: Please press correct button for my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I checked your answer and it worked. I also pressed the correct button, I just had to wait 5 minutes before I could, Stack Overflow policy. Thank you very much again

Comment: If you have questions, please feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

Please add the display field on the #signin-text.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Hope it works for you.